# SharePoint 2013 JavaScript OnClick event

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, sharepoint-2013

On our SharePoint 2013 page we have a button which runs an `EXE`

> I want to generate a `JS Alert` when the button is clicked so that users know to click RUN

The buttons are being generated by a `Content Search Web Part` which is reading from a list with a `Title` and `URL` field.

For the `EXE` my url is this: `file:///S:/Web/EmailSignature_WPF/EmailSignature_WPF.exe`

I tried to embed the `JavaScript` inline using code such as: `javascript:open('file:///S:/Web/EmailSignature_WPF/EmailSignature_WPF.exe')` or more basically: `JavaScript:alert('TEST');`

But `SharePoint` is giving me an "Invalid URL" message when I try to embed `JS` in this manner.

I have instead now moved to a `Script Editor Web Part` and am trying to add the `Alert` to the `OnClick` event of my button but this is where I am stuck.

My `Script Editor` code:

```
<script style="javascript;">
var img = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_a225dbb9_1900_49f2_afe2_ab6f5bf77adf_csr4_pictureOnTop_line1');
img.onclick="javascript:alert('event has been triggered')";</script>
```

Here is an image of the IE Debug screen which is how I'm pulling the `ID`.  This `H2` element is wrapped in an `HREF` which is wrapped in two `DIV` tags which make up an `LI`

[image: SharePoint List Item ID]

With the above snippet IE Debug is giving me this error message: 
`Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference`

I am hoping that this is as simple as misplaced quotations, or assigning the `OnClick` event to the wrong element, but I'm spinning my wheels. Any help appreciated and I'm happy to clarify

Answer (score 1):

You should associate a function to the onclick event on `img`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl40_g_a225dbb9_1900_49f2_afe2_ab6f5bf77adf_csr4_pictureOnTop_line1');
    img.onclick = function () {
    alert('event has been triggered');
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Say that your page is in the SitePages library and you use jQuery, you can add it to a folder called "js" in the SiteAssets folder, then go back to your Script Editor WP and do it like this:

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[id*="csr4_pictureOnTop_line1"]').on('click', function() {  
        alert('event has been triggered');
    });
</script>
```